# Minimum value of $F(a,b)$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization

Let $$F(a,b) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[ y_i - (ax_i+b) \right]^2$$

Find the minimum of $F$.

Evaluating the dirctional derivatives:

$$\frac{dF}{da} = \sum_{n=1}^n 2\cdot (y_i - (ax_i+b))(-x_i) \\ 
\frac{dF}{db} = \sum_{n=1}^n 2\cdot (y_i - (ax_i+b))$$

Now, we want $\nabla F = (\frac{dF}{da}, \frac{dF}{db}) = (0,0)$.

So we have (after some algebra):

$$ \sum_{n=1}^n y_i = \sum_{n=1}^n (ax_i+b)(-x_i)
\\ \sum_{n=1}^n y_i = \sum_{n=1}^n ax_i+b$$

So far so good? How should I continue? (this two equations relatively complicated)

Comment: why not plugging the first equality in the second one, or the other way round?

Comment: Anyway I just used your equations. The first one is not fine. I would correct my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first condition is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^n 2\cdot (y_i - (ax_i+b))(-x_i) =0 \iff  \sum_{n=1}^n 2\cdot (-y_ix_i + (ax_i+b)(x_i)) =0$$
$$ \iff \sum_{n=1}^n y_ix_i = \sum_{n=1}^n (ax_i+b)(x_i) \iff \sum_{n=1}^n y_ix_i =a  \sum_{n=1}^n x_i^2 +b \sum_{n=1}^n x_i$$
$$\iff \overline{xy}=\overline{x^2}a+b\bar{x}$$

The second one is:
$$\sum_{n=1}^n y_i = \sum_{n=1}^n ax_i+b \iff \bar{y}=a\bar{x}+b $$

Then you have two equations:

$$\overline{xy}=\overline{x^2}a+b\bar{x}$$
$$\bar{y}=a\bar{x}+b $$

Which gives as solution:

$$\hat a=\frac{\overline{xy}-\bar{x}\bar{y}}{\overline{x^2}-\bar{x}^2}$$
$$\hat b=\bar{y}-\hat a \bar{x}$$

Which is the same solution you can find in any text of statistics or [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression)